# Set of possible decks of cards

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Let S be the set of all 52 cards. For our purposes here, we consider a "deck" as a permutation of these 52 cards, $(c_1, c_2,...,c_{52})$ where $c_1$ is the first card, $c_2$ the second card and so on. We let $\Omega$ be the set of all possible decks.

a) Is $\Omega$ a subset of $S^{52}$ and is $S^{52}$ a subset of $\Omega%$

I think they are equal and therefore subsets of each other, but is $S^{52}$ standard notation?

b) A deck of cards is distributed to four players - A,B,C and D, each receiving $13$. The set of cards each player receives is called their hand. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the hand of player A. Is $\mathcal{A}$ a subset of $S^{52}, S^{13} \text{ or }\Omega$?

I am again unsure of notation with the S's, but is it a subset of $\Omega$ or would each subset of $\Omega$ need to have 52 elements?

c) The cards are distributed in the cycle A-B-C-D-A-B-C-D.... Given a deck, $(c_1,...,c_{52})$ what is $\mathcal{A}$?

Clearly, $(c_1,c_5,c_9,c_{13},...,c_{49})$

d) What is the subset of $\Omega$ corresponding to player A has the ace of diamonds?

Would this just be $(c_1, c_2,...,c_{52})$ where the ace of diamonds is $c_i$ and $i \equiv 1 \text{ mod }4$

Any help or clarification of notation will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)

If $X$ and $Y$ are sets then $Y^X$ denotes the set of functions $X\to Y$. Secondly $52$ can be interpreted as the set $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,51\}$ so that $S^{52}$ can be looked at as the set of functions $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,51\}\to S$.

It does harm to replace $52=\{0,1,2,3,\dots,51\}$ by $[52]=\{1,2,3,\dots,51,52\}$ but in that case I would prefer the notation $S^{[52]}$.

Every deck can be recognized as an element of $S^{[52]}$ but not vice versa. Actually the decks can be identified as the bijections. So if $\Omega$ denotes the set of all possible decks then $\Omega$ is a proper subset of $S^{[52]}$ defined by: $$\Omega=\{\omega\in S^{[52]}\mid \omega\text{ is bijective}\}\subsetneq S^{[52]}$$
Let me remark here that you can still take $S^{[52]}$ as the "set of outcomes" but in that case you must be aware of the fact that there are outcomes with $P(\{\omega\})=0$.

Any element $\omega\in\Omega$ can be denoted as $(\omega(1),\omega(2),\dots, \omega(52))$.

b) and c)

You can define:

- $A=\{4k-3\mid k\in\{1,2,\dots,13\}\}$
- $B=\{4k-2\mid k\in\{1,2,\dots,13\}\}$
- $C=\{4k-1\mid k\in\{1,2,\dots,13\}\}$
- $D=\{4k\mid k\in\{1,2,\dots,13\}\}$

These sets are disjoint, covering and equinumberable subsets of $[52]$.

Then every $\omega\in\Omega$ induces "hands" $\mathcal A(\omega),\mathcal B(\omega),\mathcal C(\omega),\mathcal D(\omega)$.

Here e.g. $\mathcal A(\omega)=\omega\upharpoonleft A$ and can be denoted as $(\omega(1),\omega(5),\dots,\omega(49))$.

So actually $\mathcal A$ is the function $\Omega\to\Omega_A=\{\omega\upharpoonleft A\mid \omega\in\Omega\}$ prescribed by $\omega\mapsto\omega\upharpoonleft A$.

d)

Let it be that $c_k$ is the ace of diamonds.

Then $\{\text{A receives ace of diamonds}\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid c_k\in\text{image of }\mathcal A(\omega)\}$.

---